# Placing a Figure at the Bottom of Each Column in a Two Column Document

Tags: two-column

I want to place two figures at the bottom of each column in a two column document. If I use [b], then it just goes to the "right" column. I could only find ways to place a figure at the bottom overlapping both columns. Thank you.

(Edit)
I am writing in a two column document. If I try

```
\begin{figure}[b]
...
\end{figure}
```

then the figure goes to the right column. I want to place the figure at the bottom of, e.g., the left column.

(Edit) Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MY.FIGURE.png}
\caption{MY.CAPTION}
\label{MY.LABEL}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MY.FIGURE.png}
\caption{MY.CAPTION}
\label{MY.LABEL}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]

I want to place two figures, one at the red box 1 (at the bottom of the left column) and the other at the red box 2 (at the bottom of the right column). Thanks!

(Edit) Oh, I think I found a way. I just wrote `\newpage` between two figures, and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing any code we can only guess. Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: Try posting a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), that way it's easier for others to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\lipsum[66]

    \begin{figure*}[!b]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{MY.CAPTION}
\label{fig:left}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{MY.CAPTION}
\label{fig:right}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```

Images are in `minipage`s inserted in float `figure*`. By help of the package ˛`stfloats` can be forced to bottom of the same page where is inserted in text. Of course, if there is sufficient space for it. If  not, it will be moved to bottom of the next page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.  First, the default maximum size for bottom floats is `0.3\textheight`, which is too small.  Second, at the end of the document, all remaining floats are implemented as [p].

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.7}% default is 0.3

\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{MY.CAPTION}
\label{MY.LABEL}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{MY.CAPTION}
\label{MY.LABEL}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```